# OpenCV HOGDescriptor undefined

Tags: c++, opencv

I wanted to use HOG but when I tried `cv::HOGDescriptor hog;` it gives me it is undefined? I included:

```
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp" 
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"    
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#include <numeric>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv::HOGDescriptor` is defined in  `"objdetect.hpp"` .you have to include this header